# System Environment Variable access in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, environment-variables

I am working on ASP.net MVC application.
I have set one Environment Variable for my project.

Now, When I run project on my machine(local host), It can read the environment variable that I have set.
But when I publish my project on IIS, project can not read the variables and because of that I can not get output.

**1.   My server is (Windows 2008 R2 Data center) - 64 bit -Service pack 1
     My IIS version is (6.1 - Service pack 1)**

I also want to perform it on

**2.   Windows 7 service pack - 1
       IIS 6.1 - Service pack 1**

So what is the way or what are the configurations for making IIS able to read environment variables.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by _can not read the variables_? Please explain your problem in more detail. Notice that you may be using IIS Express on your development machine and IIS on the production server. Also, some environment variables are user specific and the user account used by IIS cannot see the user environment variables available to your user account. With IIS Express everything is executed using your user account. This might explain your problem.

Comment: when I publish my project on the production server, it can not access environment variable which I have set on the production server. that is what I meant, Earlier I was using web.config for one value, then after I used environment for that value. It does not access to the environment variable on production server. I hope you understand my problem

Comment: How do you Access that variable? And why do you not store it in the web.config, where it belongs?

Comment: @Maharshi: I am still in the dark about what you mean with _ it can not access environment variable_. Is the variable missing or do you get an error when you try to access the variable? Please be more specific in describing your problem if you want to get assistance.

Comment: I'm having this same issue using IIS Node and IIS 7.x. I have even tried running under a user in the admin account with no success all system level env variables are undefined. I have not tried logging in under my service account user and setting up user level env vars.